# Laravel -Combination of Concatenate and COALESCE failed

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have this query:

```
$searchReports = DB::table('hr_departments AS d')
  ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS hod', function($join) use ($userCompany)
  {
    $join->on('hod.employee_code', '=', 'd.dept_head')
    ->where('hod.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
    ->where('hod.hr_status', '=', '0');
  })
   ->where('d.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
   ->select(
    'd.dept_name',
     DB::raw('CONCAT(COALESCE(hod.first_name, " ", hod.last_name),"Not Specified") AS hod_name'),
    )
   ->get();
```

I want to join hr_employees table with hr_departments table. Concatenate first_name and last_name of the hod as the full_name. Then if hod does not exist for the department it should coalesce and displayed "Not Specified".

But for all the hod, it didn't display last_name. But,rather concatenate only first_name and "Not Specified"

For example:

> AkweteyNot Specified

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reverse the order of `CONCAT` and `COALESCE`, and do the former first:

```php
->select(
    'd.dept_name',
     DB::raw('COALESCE(CONCAT(hod.first_name, " ", hod.last_name), "Not Specified") AS hod_name'),
)
->get();
```

Note that the behavior of `CONCAT` is that if any of the values be `NULL`, then it will return `NULL`.  In that case, the code as written above would fall back to `COALESCE`, which will display the alternative message.

I would probably rather do it this way:

```sql
CASE WHEN hod.employee_code IS NOT NULL
     THEN CONCAT(hod.first_name, ' ', hod.last_name)
     ELSE 'Not Specified' END
```

The above `CASE` expression more properly checks the join column and based on that shows the names or the backup message.